# Magento 2.3 : single checkbox not selected in massStatus

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, magento2.3

I created ui grid in my custom module.

But, When I select single checkbox for massStatus at that time, it will select all checkbox instead of single checkbox.

This is my vendor_module_entity_listing.xml file :

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing.vendor_module_entity_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing.vendor_module_entity_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">custom_module_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Type</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/add</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="vendor_module_entity_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">VendorModuleFilterPool</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">reason_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="cacheRequests" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </bookmark>
    <component name="columns_controls">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing.vendor_module_entity_listing.custom_module_columns</item>
                </item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </component>

    <filterSearch name="fulltext">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing.vendor_module_entity_listing_data_source</item>
                <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing.vendor_module_entity_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing.vendor_module_entity_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filterSearch>
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing.vendor_module_entity_listing.custom_module_columns</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing.vendor_module_entity_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                </item>
                <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing.vendor_module_entity_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing.vendor_module_entity_listing.custom_module_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>

            <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <filterSelect name="store_id">
            <argument name="optionsProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options</argument>
            </argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">${ $.parentName }</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
                    <item name="captionValue" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSelect>

    </filters>

    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing.vendor_module_entity_listing.custom_module_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <action name="is_delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="vendor/module/massDelete">
                    </item>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>

        <action name="is_active">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">is_active</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Change status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">enable</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="vendor/module/massStatus">
                        <param name="status">1</param>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">disable</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disable</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="vendor/module/massStatus">
                        <param name="status">0</param>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>

    </massaction>

    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing.vendor_module_entity_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing.vendor_module_entity_listing.custom_module_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>
</container>

<columns name="custom_module_columns">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing.vendor_module_entity_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
            </item>
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing.vendor_module_entity_listing.custom_module_columns</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_entity_listing.vendor_module_entity_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>


    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">status_id</item>
            </item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>

    <column name="reason_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Reason ID</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="title">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="sort_order">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sort Order</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="is_active">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Active</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

   <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ReasonActions">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
               <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
               <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">reason_id</item>
               <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">180</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </actionsColumn>
</columns>
```

Where I do mistake?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `primaryFieldName` and selectionsColumn `indexField` both are different. Set both field's value equal.

change `indexField` value as like below code :

```
<selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">reason_id</item>
            </item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
        </argument>
</selectionsColumn>
```

I hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: It's working. Thanks..